# How to set the Ruby version when calling Ruby from NodeJS using child_process.exec

Tags: ruby, node.js, child-process

I need to run a ruby script from within a node.js app. The script requires Ruby 2.0 but when I try to run the script it keeps running 1.8 and failing. I have tried

```
child_process.exec("rvm use 2.0.0;ruby file.rb", {cwd: 'directory_name'}, function(err, stdout){
  console.log(stdout)
});
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `rvm use 2.0.0; ruby -v` output?

Comment: it outputs ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

Comment: Do you get that when you run in terminal or when you use `exec()`?

Comment: When using exec. Terminal works fine.

Comment: try to determinate where the installation path of Ruby version that you want to execute, then call ruby interpreter from that path. But its not recommended that you have different versions of interpreters running in the same OS, the latest installed of course might overwrite the configurations from the previous one

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to switching the gemset/ruby version before executing ruby, is to generate a RVM wrapper that does the job for you.

```
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm wrapper 2.0.0@<gemset> <prefix> # gesmset and prefix are optional but I'd use them for clarification
```

Running this generates a ruby stub in `~/.rvm/bin` or, if you have installed RVM system wide, in `/usr/local/rvm/bin`. This stub automatically switches to the specified ruby-version/gemset when executed.

Your node script could look like this:

```
child_process.exec("~/.rvm/bin/<prefix>_ruby file.rb", {cwd: 'directory_name'}, function(err, stdout){
  console.log(stdout)
});
```

Comment: OK I'll try this. It needs to run on heroku and I also will need to run bundle manually so not sure this will work. It gives me more to work with though. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it won't. Its also not working on my local either when being executed via exec()